# Poor Validation Acc and High Validation Loss for resnet50

Tags: python, keras, resnet, transfer-learning

After trying out VGG16 and having really good results, I was trying to train a ResNet50 Model from Imagenet. First I set all layers to trainable because I have a large Dataset and did the same with VGG16, but my results were quite bad.

[image]

Then I tried to set the layers to not trainable and see if it gets better, but the results were still bad.

[image]

My original images are of size 384x384 but I resized them to 224x224. Is that the issue? Or did I do something wrong while implementing it?

```
from keras import Input, Model
from keras.applications import ResNet50
from keras.layers import AveragePooling2D, Flatten, Dense, Dropout
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras_preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator


class example:
    def __init__(self):
        # define the names of the classes
        self.CLASSES = ["nok", "ok"]

        # initialize the initial learning rate, batch size, and number of
        # epochs to train for
        self.INIT_LR = 1e-4
        self.BS = 32
        self.NUM_EPOCHS = 32

    def build_model(self, train_path):
        train_data_path = train_path
        train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255, validation_split=0.25)

        train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_data_path,
        target_size=(224,224),
        color_mode="rgb",
        batch_size=self.BS,
        class_mode='categorical',
        subset='training')

        validation_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_data_path,
        target_size=(224, 224),
        color_mode="rgb",
        batch_size=self.BS,
        class_mode='categorical',
        subset='validation')

        # load the ResNet-50 network, ensuring the head FC layer sets are left off
        baseModel = ResNet50(weights="imagenet", include_top=False,
        input_tensor = Input(shape=(224, 224, 3)))

        # construct the head of the model that will be placed on top of the the base model
        headModel = baseModel.output
        headModel = AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(7, 7))(headModel)
        headModel = Flatten(name="flatten")(headModel)
        headModel = Dense(256, activation="relu")(headModel)
        headModel = Dropout(0.5)(headModel)
        headModel = Dense(len(self.CLASSES), activation="softmax")(headModel)

        # place the head FC model on top of the base model (this will become the actual model we will train)
        model = Model(inputs=baseModel.input, outputs=headModel)

        for layer in baseModel.layers:
            layer.trainable = True

        # compile the model
        opt = Adam(lr=self.INIT_LR)#, decay=self.INIT_LR / self.NUM_EPOCHS)
        model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer=opt,
                  metrics=["accuracy"])

        from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping
        import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

        checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('resnetModel.h5', monitor='val_accuracy', verbose=1, save_best_only=True,
                                 save_weights_only=False, mode='auto', period=1)

        early = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_accuracy', min_delta=0, patience=6, verbose=1, mode='auto')

        hist = model.fit_generator(steps_per_epoch=self.BS, generator=train_generator,
                               validation_data=validation_generator, validation_steps=32, epochs=self.NUM_EPOCHS,
                               callbacks=[checkpoint, early])

        plt.plot(hist.history['accuracy'])
        plt.plot(hist.history['val_accuracy'])
        plt.plot(hist.history['loss'])
        plt.plot(hist.history['val_loss'])
        plt.title("model accuracy")
        plt.ylabel("Accuracy")
        plt.xlabel("Epoch")
        plt.legend(["Accuracy", "Validation Accuracy", "loss", "Validation Loss"])
        plt.show()

        plt.figure(1)

import tensorflow as tf

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = example()
    config = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto()
    config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
    sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(config=config)
    x.build_model("C:/Users/but/Desktop/dataScratch/Train")
```

I have 2 Classes which contain images of integrated circuits with defect and non defect images. My Batch Size is 32, Epoches is 32, LR is 1e-4.

Here are example images:

[image]

This is a defect image

[image]

This is an ok image

Comment: Could you make the data accessible and post the full code, otherwise it will get difficult for others to track this.

Comment: I added full code and example images of the classes. the dataset is private and can't be shared unfortunately. But the images look very similar with the defect images having scratches on different areas and the ok images looking like good ICs.

Comment: How large is your large dataset? 100s, 1000s, tens of thousands?

Comment: Also, this does not answer your question at all, but this seems like a use-case where a classical CV approach would probably get quite good results, I'm not sure that deep learning is necessarily helpful here.

Comment: @JohannesAck I have 2000 Ok Images and 2000 defect images. What do you mean with classical CV approach?
You could be right, but this is part of my master thesis to analyze and experiment if it is possible to use deep nets for inspecting ICs. There are many papers where Deep nets are used to detect surface defects in steel, fabric, etc.